# Adding incremental integers to end of string in C

Tags: c, arrays, printf

need some help with sprintf. I keep running into the error 'sprintf' makes pointer from integer without a cast.

a was declared in the main function to be char a[1000]

```
int
next_statement(char *a, int n) {
    int c, i,z;
    for (i=0; i < n && (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++) {
        if (c == CHAR_SEMI) {
            consume_char('\n');
            break;
        }
        a[i] = c;
    }
    for(z=0; z<n;z++){
        if (c == CHAR_SEMI) {
            a[i-3] = 'x';
            sprintf(a[i-2], "%d", z);
            a[i-1] = ';';
            a[i] = '\0';

            return i; /* index when ; was read, so the length of saved. */
        }

    else if (i >= n) {
        printf("%s Line too long.\n", ERROR_PREFIX);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a[i-2]` is a `char` not a `char*`. `sprintf` expects a `char*` as its first argument

Answer (score 4):

In this line `a[i-2]` is single character. It will not represent the character pointer.

```
sprintf(a[i-2], "%d", z);
```

so you can try like this,

```
sprintf(&a[i-2], "%d", z);
```

From the `man` page of `sprintf`

```
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

It requires the first argument as a character pointer.

Answer (score 3):

As you've written, `a[i-2]` denotes the `char`, not a `char *`, as required by [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) as it's first parameter. You need to supply the pointer for the *string* to write on.

`[]` is the *Array subscripting* operator. You need not use that operator. So, instead of

```
sprintf(a[i-2], "%d", z);
```

you can use like

```
sprintf( (a+i-2), "%d", z);
```

Answer (score 2):

sprintf() takes first argument as a `char *` type, But your mention here as `a[i-2]` character type,

So you can give like this

```
 sprintf( ((a+i)-2) ,"%d", z);
```